# Exception in Destructor (c#)?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.0, garbage-collection, destructor

I have this class :

```
public class TempFileRef
    {
        public readonly string FilePath;

        public TempFileRef(string filePath)
        {
            FilePath = filePath;
        }

        ~TempFileRef()
        {
            File.Delete(FilePath);    //<== what happens if exception ?
        }
    }
```

Question :

What happens if there is an Exception in the destructor ?

1) will it break the other finalization's in the F-Queue ?

2) I i'll wrap it with `Try` and `Cache` - I will `NEVER` know that there was an error

3) `what` should I do here ?

### edit

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) pattern for it based on `"if I **forget** to call the Dispose method - so the GC will do it eventually.... it is better later then never..."`. So my question is **specially** about exception in the Finilize ( destructor)

Comment: I would call it "[Finalize method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s71x931.aspx)", not "Destructor", although it uses destructor syntax.

Comment: @UweKeim - the C# reference calls them destructors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664609%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :

> Exceptions that occur during destructor execution are worth special
>   mention. If an exception occurs during destructor execution, and that
>   exception is not caught, then the execution of that destructor is
>   terminated and the destructor of the base class (if any) is called. If
>   there is no base class (as in the case of the object type) or if there
>   is no base class destructor, then the exception is discarded.

Comment: This is probably an outdated VS2003 / .NET 1 thing. See other answer.

Answer (score 15):

This actually depends on the .NET framework

For example in [.NET 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.80).aspx) and [.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you application will be terminated

> If Finalize or an override of Finalize throws an exception, and the runtime is not 
>   hosted by an application that overrides the default
>   policy, the runtime terminates the process and no active try-finally
>   blocks or finalizers are executed. This behavior ensures process
>   integrity if the finalizer cannot free or destroy resources.

In contrast in [.NET 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), only that finalizer will be terminated and your application will continue running:

> If Finalize or an override of Finalize throws an exception, the
>   runtime ignores the exception, terminates that Finalize method, and
>   continues the finalization process.

What you actually trying to do is to implement an `IDisposable` pattern, so instead leaving this work to a finilazer, do it in the progrmatically called `Dispose`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of deleting a file in finalizer consider implementing `IDisposable` interface.

> Exceptions that occur during destructor execution are worth special
>   mention. If an exception occurs during destructor execution, and that
>   exception is not caught, then the execution of that destructor is
>   terminated and the destructor of the base class (if any) is called. If
>   there is no base class (as in the case of the object type) or if there
>   is no base class destructor, then the exception is discarded.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664609%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: The MSDN pattern for it  based on " if I forget to call the Dispose method - so the GC will do it eventually.... it is better later then never...". So my question is specially about the Finilize ( destructor). - please see my edit.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, surely the answer then is to not forget.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Destructor, it's not `C++`, use a `Dispose()` method of `IDisposbale` interface that you should implement. Call Dispose() esplicitly from your code, or use your class with `using` , like (say)

```
using(var tempRef = new TempFileRef())
{
    //do something here

} //Dispose will be called after this line.
```

**EDIT**

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx)

> If Finalize or an override of Finalize throws an exception, and the
>   runtime is not hosted by an application that overrides the default
>   policy, the runtime terminates the process and no active try-finally
>   blocks or finalizers are executed. This behavior ensures process
>   integrity if the finalizer cannot free or destroy resources.

In other words: do not call something in Finalizer that *can possibly* fail. Use Dispose, instead, and ensure it was called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @downvoter: what is wrong with this post. Is it different from the most voted annswer here?